# Does Meta-sites affect the condition during private/public beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, meta-faq

As title says:

Does the meta of a beta stackexchange site affect the values to met conditions during private/public beta?

I'm talking about

- `question per day`
- `%answered`
- `avid/total users`
- `answer ratio`
- `visit/day`

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't. The values you list are only for the main site, and they don't include the values for the associated meta site.

Comment: I can corroborate that. The Area 51 stats do not include meta activity.